# How to render an inline template a fixed number of times

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a search results screen and in the results payload supplied I get a pageCount number back.  With this, I intend to create a simple pager.

So really I need to do this:

```
    <!-- ko for(var i = 0; i < pageCount(); i++) -->
        <div data-bind="html: 'Page '+$index()"></div>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but you get what I mean.  I suppose I could create another observableArray of integers on the View Model with each item representing a page, but this seems like overkill.  However, it may be my only option?!

Oh well, I thought I'd better ask, as sometimes there's some killer function which creates a range on the fly and then I can foreach over that bad boy.

Anyhooo, I think you see what I mean.
thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would use `foreach: new Array(pageCount())`:

```
<!-- ko foreach: new Array(pageCount())  -->
        <div data-bind="html: 'Page '+$index()"></div>
<!-- /ko -->​
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your requirements correctly, take a look at Michael Best's 'Repeat' plugin:

https://github.com/mbest/knockout-repeat

Example:

```
<div data-bind="repeat: pageCount" data-repeat-bind="html: 'Page '+$index"></div>
```